# Хранить пароль к MYSQL в .htaccess и не в файле php это будет надежно?

Tags: .htaccess, php, mysql

Всем привет, меня атаковали и не знаю конечно как но решил переделать сайт и хочу знать является ли файл `.htaccess` более надежным в сравнении в обычным файлом php

Потом, в логике php ты открывал соединение и потом надо было его закрывать с `mysql_close`.

В `.htaccess` что надо делать так чтобы после загрузки файла в конце закрывало соединение? или оно делает автоматически?

Я прописал в файле

```
php_value mysql.default_user ЛОГИН
php_value mysql.default_password ПАРОЛЬ
```

и оно работает, но я не знаю вот что: `.htaccess`, он может быть подверген атаке с легкостью или же это таки невозможно?

Comment: Можно в htaccess хранить пароли не в чистом тексте, а как хэш. Тогда это безопаснее.

Comment: @Sharbag, как использовать захешированный пароль?

Comment: В .htaccess добавляешь: 
AuthUserFile /password/path/.htpasswd

А в .htpasswd строки типа:
loginname:$apr1$tme6Ndj8$yvuzPW/16laNgzFffNOwV.

Генератор для такого файла есть тут: http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

Comment: @Sharbag, я про то, что если пароль уже захеширован, то каким образом скормить его mysql?

Comment: @Fike, хм. Пардоньте. Что-то я действительно не в тему подал эту идею, наверное. Хотя если это пхп-приложение, то там, как нибудь, можно было бы перевести хэшик в нормальный пароль, не? А вообще, Iranda прав.

Comment: @Sharbag, вся суть криптографического хэша в том что он необратим (одно из требований к такому типу хэшей). Язык программирования тут непричём. Если пароль изменён обратимым образом то это повышает не безопасность, а запутанность.

P.S. рекомендую почитать про хэширование паролей там: http://habrahabr.ru/post/210760/

Comment: @Sharbag смысл хэшировать пароль, если он без проблем дехэшируется обратно? Тогда можно и не хэшировать вообще.

Answer (score 3):

Храните пароль вне корня Вашего сайта. `.htaccess` не предназначен для хранения пароля к базе.

Comment: Как дополнение к этому ответу вероятно интересно будет почитать:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/90539/  
И связанные вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Если злоумышленник получил доступ к файлам сервера то он посмотрит пароль и в php-файле и в  .htaccess поэтому надо искать именно место взлома сначала, ну и конечно же посмотреть чтобы шелла никакого не осталось на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше php, .htaccess просто не везде работает. И вообще какая-то несуразица получается.

Не там вы проблему ищите, если сайт ломанули то сделали это почти наверняка не через получение доступа к базе, а через ошибки в скриптах.

P.S. приведённые вами строки из htaccess устанавливают логин и пароль используемые модулем mysql по умолчанию. Они просто позволяют не задавать логин и пароль при подключении к базе (модуль mysql в таком случае видимо использует значение по умолчанию). В остальном процесс работы с базой выглядит точно так-же.

P.P.S. модуль mysql, который вы используете, признан устаревшим и небезопасным. В одной из следующих версий php его удалят. Вместо него рекомендуется использовать mysqli или pdo-mysql.